# show/hide elements dynamically using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table which has four columns namely Code, Name, Quantity and Price. Out of these, I want to change the content/element of Quantity column dynamically. Normally, it should show the  element with quantity displayed in it and when user click on  element, I want to show the  element so user can edit the quantity. I'm trying to implement as per "Example 2" on this [knockout documentation link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html).

Following is my code :

**Page Viewmodel**

```
function OrderVM (vm) {
    var self = this;
    self.OrderNo= ko.observable(vm.OrderNo());   
    .....
    .....
    self.OrderedProducts = ko.observableArray([]);
    for (i = 0; i < vm.OrderedProducts().length; i++) {
        var p = new ProductVM(vm.OrderedProducts()[i]);
        self.OrderedProducts.push(p);
    }
    .....
}

function ProductVM(vm) {
    var self = this;

    self.Code = ko.observable(vm.Code());
    self.Name = ko.observable(vm.Name());
    self.Quantity = ko.observable(vm.Quantity());
    self.Price = ko.observable(vm.Price());
    self.IsEditing = ko.observable(false);

    this.edit = function () {
        self.IsEditing(true);
    }
}
```

In my **Razor view** I have following code :

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:OrderedProducts">
<tr>
    <td class="lalign"><span data-bind="text:Code"/></td>
    <td class="lalign"><span data-bind="text:Name" /></td>
    <td class="ralign" style="padding:1px!important;">
        <span data-bind="visible: !IsEditing(), text: Quantity, click: edit"
            style="width:100%;float:left;text-align:right;padding-right:10px;" />
        <input data-bind="value: Quantity,visible:IsEditing,hasfocus:IsEditing"
               style="width:100%;text-align:right;padding-right:10px;" />
    </td>
    <td class="ralign rightbordernone" style="padding-right:20px!important;"><span data-bind="text:Price"/></td>
</tr>
```

With above code, when I click on span element in my Quantity column of table, "edit" function is called and "IsEditing" value is set to true but I don't see input element visible in my cell. After clicking on span element, If I look at the html using "Inspect Element", I can still see the  element only and not  but on screen in my view, I see neither span nor input element.

This is very simple logic and executes as expected however final result on view is not as expected. Can anyone help me to detect what's wrong with above code?

Comment: try changing visible:IsEditing, to visible:IsEditing()

Comment: I tried "IsEditing()" but it doesn't work

Comment: setup a sample fiddle so it easy to track what causing the issue . cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is tricky. It lies in the fact that `span` is *not* a self-closing element. This will work:

```
<td>
    <span data-bind="visible: !IsEditing(), text: Quantity, click: edit"></span>
    <input data-bind="value: Quantity, visible: IsEditing, hasfocus: IsEditing" />
</td>
```

Here's a full demo:

```js
function ProductVM(vm) {
    var self = this;

    self.Code = ko.observable(vm.Code());
    self.Name = ko.observable(vm.Name());
    self.Quantity = ko.observable(vm.Quantity());
    self.Price = ko.observable(vm.Price());
    self.IsEditing = ko.observable(false);

    this.edit = function () {
        self.IsEditing(true);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings({ OrderedProducts: [new ProductVM({
    Code: function() { return 1; },
    Name: function() { return "Apples"; },
    Quantity: function() { return 10; },
    Price: function() { return 12.50; }
})]})
```

```css
span { padding: 5px; background: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

(Click "10" e.g. the Quantity for demo.)
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: OrderedProducts">
    <tr>
      <td><span data-bind="text:Code"></span></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text:Name"></span></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="visible: !IsEditing(), text: Quantity, click: edit"></span>
        <input data-bind="value: Quantity, visible: IsEditing, hasfocus: IsEditing" />
      </td>
      <td><span data-bind="text:Price"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Remember, **the same holds for `div` elements**, don't use them in a self-closing manner or Knockout will fool you when you least expect it.

Comment: you nailed it @Jeroen now it works as expected. thanks.