# Dynamically show / hide with Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying a simple thing with KnockoutJS - dynamically show a section when a radio group has a `'y'` value.

```js
'use strict';

console.log('running js..', ko);

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.termsAccepted = ko.observable('n');
};

// Bind our ViewModel to our View
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script>console.log('loading knockout')</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script>console.log('knockout loaded')</script>
<h4>Dynamically hide / show section</h4>
<p>I would like to show a section when the terms are actually accepted, and hide it otherwise</p>

<p><strong>Terms accepted</strong> <span style="color: red" data-bind="text: termsAccepted"/></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="esign" value="y" data-bind="checked: termsAccepted"> <label for="esignTrue">I agree.</label>
<input type="radio" name="esign" value="n" data-bind="checked: termsAccepted"> <label for="esignFalse">I do not agree.</label></p>

<div data-bind="visible: termsAccepted">
  Only showing when terms are accepted...
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: termsAccepted === 'y'">
  Only showing when terms are accepted...
</div>

<!-- ko if: termsAccepted === 'y' -->
<div>
  Only showing when terms are accepted...
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

It seems pretty straightforward, but the sections are not hiding / showing as expected.

I have verified it is not because of using self-closing tag as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701982/show-hide-elements-dynamically-using-knockout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're binding to a function expression rather than simply to an observable you have to unwrap the observables within the expression with parens.

https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html

```js
'use strict';

var ViewModel = function() {
  this.termsAccepted = ko.observable('n');
};

// Bind our ViewModel to our View
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h4>Dynamically hide / show section</h4>
<p>I would like to show a section when the terms are actually accepted, and hide it otherwise</p>

<p><strong>Terms accepted</strong> <span style="color: red" data-bind="text: termsAccepted"/></p>
<p><input type="radio" name="esign" value="y" data-bind="checked: termsAccepted"> <label for="esignTrue">I agree.</label>
<input type="radio" name="esign" value="n" data-bind="checked: termsAccepted"> <label for="esignFalse">I do not agree.</label></p>

<div data-bind="visible: termsAccepted() === 'y'">
  Only showing when terms are accepted...
</div>
<!-- ko if: termsAccepted() === 'y' -->
<div>
  Only showing when terms are accepted...
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```